# Edit "Media Duration" metadata on MP4 file

Tags: linux, video-conversion, metadata, mp4, exiftool

I have some video files which were converted to MP4, but not quite correctly. When I examine one with exiftool, I see these metadata values:

```
Duration                        : 0:11:23
Track Duration                  : 0:11:23
Media Duration                  : 0:04:13
```

That last one is incorrect. In VLC media player, the videos play fine, but the tool I'm using to play them in a web app (Flowplayer) takes the "Media Duration" value seriously and truncates the video.

To fix the metadata I tried

```
exiftool -"Media Duration"="0:11:23" video_1.mp4
```

But I got

```
Warning: Sorry, Media is not writable
Nothing to do.
```

Sudo didn't help. According to its man page and [web site](https://exiftool.org/), exiftool *can* read and write metadata on MP4 files, but "ExifTool will not rewrite a file if it detects a significant problem with the file format."

How can I fix those files?

---

EDIT: I've had no luck with ffmpeg or mediainfo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. Rather than editing the metadata, I re-encoded the files using ffmpeg, in such a way that the video and audio content was simply copied and wrapped in a new, error-free MP4 container. Here's the command:

```
ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy video_1_fixed.mp4
```

Comment: Just wanted to say, thanks a lot, this helped me right now.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why the listed exiftool command didn't work.

First, "Media Duration" isn't the name of a tag, it's the description.  From [ExifTool FAQ #2](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q2)

> …by default it prints descriptions, not tag names, for the information it extracts.    …   Note that descriptions often contain spaces between words, but tag names never do. Also, tag names are always English, regardless of the [`-lang` setting](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#lang-LANG). To print the tag names instead instead of descriptions, use the [`-s` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#s-NUM--short) when extracting information

The second problem is that the `MediaDuration` tag isn't a writable tag (see the [QuickTime MediaHeader Tags](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/QuickTime.html#MediaHeader)).

Comment: Admittedly, this is a necro-post answer, but I thought I should bring up the reasons why the original exiftool command didn't work.